# Error: Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I used testcafe 1.8.8 with node 8.14.0 and npm 6.4.1. Test cases worked fine. After a while once I clone this project as a new I am geting below message when runing the test cases.

> Error: Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser
> connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device
> failure. at BrowserSet._waitConnectionsOpened
> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo2/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/browser-set.ts:91:30)
> at Promise.resolve.then
> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo2/node_modules/testcafe/src/runner/browser-set.ts:114:35)
> at  code: 'E1004', data: [] }

As I found may FAQ s are showing this as testcafe version issue , but I tried all there given versions but still geting same error.

Any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update TestCafe to the latest version and check if the issue is persist. Please note that [the minimal Node.js version for TestCafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/package.json) is `v10.0.0`:

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=10.0.0"
},
```